# Detect what file AJAX request is coming from in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on a small application that has many AJAX requests being made to one file in particular.

Once the request is received, I would like the PHP action file to log where the request is coming from and make further decisions. In the PHP action file, I tried using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine the location of the AJAX submission, however this returns the location of the PHP action file instead.

Is there any way to use `HTTP`, `$_POST`, or the like to achieve this without needing to manually append another variable to the `post` object in each form?

Looking for something like:

```
$origin = $_POST['origin'];
echo $origin; // returns either 'form-submit.js' or '/path/form-page.php'
```

Comment: By file do you mean the javascript file or the url?

Comment: Does `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` give you what you want?

Comment: If you control the pages making the requests, you can modify your AJAX request to send the origin along with whatever else it's sending.

Comment: @AlexanderKleinhans looking for the JS file or the URL, updated the question example. thanks

Comment: @Don'tPanic the object of this question is to not have to do exactly that. See second paragraph.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. Having magical behaviour based on where a request comes from is confusing and hard to maintain. If you want an endpoint to behave differently under different conditions, then have the client ask for the differences explicitly.

Comment: @Quentin the desired behavior is more for tracking and data to understand what needs to change within the existing app - not exactly looking to perform other front-end tasks. However, why would you describe this to be "magical", "confusing", and "hard to maintain"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how I missed that. I agree with Quentin, though. It doesn't seem like the server should need to be concerned with who the client is, just with the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without adding another parameter to your Ajax request, the closest thing you can get to what you're looking for is to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in PHP to get the value of the `Referer` header which says what page the user was coming from.

Of course this value can't be trusted, can't be guaranteed it will be present (some may disable it) or relied upon in general.

You're better off adding another parameter to your request, but this of course can be modified client side too.

Comment: This actually works great! However, as seen in the comments above and describe in your answer as not-to-be-trusted, is there a specific reason that this value could be unreliable or tampered with?

Comment: It's unreliable because it is sent by the client (browser) so they can easily manipulate it to be something else or use plugins to disable it from being sent completely.  So don't rely on it being present, and if it is, it's possible it doesn't represent the actual referer though in most cases it's fine.  Just be aware it's easy to manipulate.